# Blazor Server, get return value from Async Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, c#, asynchronous, blazor

Racking my brain trying to get this working, I can get synchronous JS values from JS to Blazor, but async doesn't get sent over.

Let's say I have the following code:

.razor

```
private async Task GetJSRemoteIP()
{
    string remoteIP = await JSRunTime.InvokeAsync<string>("getIPadr");
}
```

.js

```
function getIPadr() {
return "works!"
}
```

however, if I change the js to an async function with return, it never gets sent back to blazor, like so:

.js

```
async function getIPadr() {
const response = await fetch("https://api.ipify.org?format=json");
const jsonData = await response.json();
return jsonData;

}
```

What do I need to do to get the async function value back into blazor with return?

Comment: When you use async javascript function you get a promise and other values are wrapped in a resolved promise automatically.

Comment: Thanks- do you know how I can unwrap the promise?

Comment: Right now travelling, you can get idea here for example  async function sayHi() {
    return Promise.resolve('Hi');
}

Comment: @SurinderSingh i tried what you said but it didn't work, instead of the value it's returning the promise itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. However, there seems to be a problem when returning the JSON data. Presumably, the JSON object is not implicitly getting typecasted to a string type.

Since the response is a JSON, you can access the data member directly and return it.

```
return jsonData.ip;
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly convert it to a string and send it back to the server.

```
return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Above will require adding a deserializing mechanism on the server side to get IP from the JSON.